# Problem with unclear error message

Tags: math-mode, errors

```
\begin{align*}
P(A) \cap P(B) & = \lbrace x \mid x \in P(A) \and x \in P(B) \rbrace \\
               & = \lbrace x \mid x \subseteq A \and x \subseteq B \rbrace \\
               & = \lbrace x \mid x \subset (A \cap B) \rbrace \\
               & = \lbrace x \mid x \in P(A \cap B) \rbrace \\
               & = P(A \cap B) 
\end{align*}
```

Error in the first line: `Missing \endgroup inserted`

What should I do?

Comment: Replace `\and` by `\wedge`.

Comment: The symbol for “logical or” cannot be called `\or`, which is a TeX primitive, so it's called `\lor`; similarly, “logical and” is called `\land` (but `\and` exists, with a completely unrelated meaning and usage).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off topic: you mixed `\subseteq` and `\subset`.

Answer (score 7):

You probably want a "logical and" which is `\land` and not `\and`.

[image: logical and]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
P(A) \cap P(B) & = \lbrace x \mid x \in P(A) \land x \in P(B) \rbrace \\
               & = \lbrace x \mid x \subseteq A \land x \subseteq B \rbrace \\
               & = \lbrace x \mid x \subset (A \cap B) \rbrace \\
               & = \lbrace x \mid x \in P(A \cap B) \rbrace \\
               & = P(A \cap B) 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```